# "Input string was not in a correct format" error with ASP.Net QueryString

Tags: asp.net, formview, request.querystring

Folks, I'm now having an annoying error with ASP.Net QueryStrings.

I used the querystring to pass values from one page to another in my ASP web app. 
So that, I can change the form viewing mode of the destination page based on my querystring value.

The redirect code is as below:

`Response.Redirect("~/Exams/Questions/ExamQuestionEntry.aspx?mode=1&examCode=" & examCode)`

When I load the  `ExamQuestionEntry` page, I change the FormView based on the `mode` value. For instance, 0 is default ReadOnly mode, 1 is Insert mode and 2 is Edit mode.
But, here's the weird thing... 
When I set the mode vale to 1, setting the FormView to Insert mode, everything's fine and work well. 
But, when I set the mode to either 0 or 2, I've got the error... 
`"Input string was not in a correct format."`

I've tried every alternatives and solutions I can imagine, and finally I can't honestly figure out why this is happening.

Comment: What is the actual value being converted to int? BTW, What would you do if the user will change the value manually?

Comment: There is an error handling in the destination page load event. If the mode value is not present or it isn't one of three values, an error will be shown.

Comment: Can you debug and see which string are you trying to convert?

Comment: Actually, there isn't any conversion occurred in here. I just set the mode value to 1, and exam code is just a normal string value.

Comment: Show code for composing of the redirect url and code from the target page where you getting and parse parameters values

Comment: Here's all the code related to the redirecting with the query string... `Protected Sub btnAddQuestion_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddQuestion.Click
        Dim examCode As String = Request.QueryString("examCode")
        Response.Redirect("~/Exams/Questions/ExamQuestionEntry.aspx?mode=2&examCode=" & examCode)
    End Sub`

Comment: The `examCode` values are mostly `EX001`, `EX002` and etc....

Comment: The error is only occurring in this page and in that Click event. So, I think we don't actually need to consider how the destination page works.

Comment: In which line the error happens?

Comment: It's in the Redirect statement....!